# Percona Xtrabackup 8.0 failed and showed error "xtrabackup: Error: unknown argument: '/var/lib/mysql/data'"

Tags: python, mysql, backup, percona

I'm using Openstack Trove to create and manage backup mysql8 with Percona Xtrabackup 8.0.

When trying to create a backup for a DB, I encounter this problem: Backup failed because of Xtrabackup has an unknown argument.

Everything else looks fine to me, so I couldn't understand what wrong. Anyone had this issue or can shed some light on it? Thank you so much! Here is the log:

> ```
> 2020-01-03 03:04:31.313 1259 DEBUG trove.guestagent.strategies.backup.mysql_impl [-] xtrabackup: recognized server arguments: --datadir=/var/lib/mysql/data --tmpdir=/var/tmp --innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:10M:autoextend --innodb_buffer_pool_size=600M --innodb_file_per_table=1 --innodb_log_files_in_group=2 --innodb_log_file_size=50M --innodb_log_buffer_size=25M --open_files_limit=2048 --server-id=1975412137
> xtrabackup: recognized client arguments: --port=3306 --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --user=os_admin --password=* --host=127.0.0.1 --stream=xbstream --user=os_admin --password=* --host=127.0.0.1
> xtrabackup: Error: unknown argument: '/var/lib/mysql/data'
>  check_process /opt/guest-agent-venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/trove/guestagent/strategies/backup/mysql_impl.py:94
> 2020-01-03 03:04:31.314 1259 ERROR trove.guestagent.strategies.backup.mysql_impl [-] Xtrabackup did not complete successfully.
> 2020-01-03 03:04:31.314 1259 ERROR trove.guestagent.backup.backupagent [-] Error saving backup: e6b8729e-7646-4e25-8e58-49e49eab81a4.: trove.guestagent.strategies.backup.base.BackupError
> 2020-01-03 03:04:31.314 1259 ERROR trove.guestagent.backup.backupagent Traceback (most recent call last):
> 2020-01-03 03:04:31.314 1259 ERROR trove.guestagent.backup.backupagent   File "/opt/guest-agent-venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/trove/guestagent/backup/backupagent.py", line 114, in stream_backup_to_storage
> 2020-01-03 03:04:31.314 1259 ERROR trove.guestagent.backup.backupagent     return meta
> 2020-01-03 03:04:31.314 1259 ERROR trove.guestagent.backup.backupagent   File "/opt/guest-agent-venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/trove/guestagent/strategies/backup/base.py", line 96, in __exit__
> 2020-01-03 03:04:31.314 1259 ERROR trove.guestagent.backup.backupagent     raise BackupError
> 2020-01-03 03:04:31.314 1259 ERROR trove.guestagent.backup.backupagent trove.guestagent.strategies.backup.base.BackupError
> 2020-01-03 03:04:31.314 1259 ERROR trove.guestagent.backup.backupagent
> ```

Comment: Which Trove version? Looks worthy of a [upstream bug report](https://storyboard.openstack.org/#!/project/openstack/trove) if using a modern version.

Comment: **trove-common**  _1:8.0.0-0ubuntu1~cloud0._
Maybe not the latest version, I'll try to update to the latest one. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Or you could do an [ubuntu bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openstack-trove) too/instead.

Answer (score 0):

`xtrabackup` is not entirely helpful showing what it did recognise, it would help if it also showed the entire command line as received (especially if it turns out it read a defaults file which means the problem could be entirely elsewhere).

In the meantime, you need to see exactly what `trove/guestagent/strategies/backup/mysql_impl.py` is doing at line 94.

I would hazard guess that it's building up a command-line string and somewhere (other than the `--datadir=/var/lib/mysql/data` which xtrabackup says it recognized) is another occurrence of `/var/lib/mysql/data`. If you can print out the full command line before executing it should offer a clue.